# Mocking a class with an explicitly implemented interface using Foq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, f#, mocking, foq

I wanted to mock an entityframwork `DbSet` using [Foq](http://foq.codeplex.com/). It goes something like:

```ml
let patients = 
    ([
        Patient(Guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001");
        Patient(Guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002");
        Patient(Guid "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003");
    ]).AsQueryable()

let mockPatSet = Mock<DbSet<Patient>>.With(fun x ->
    <@ 
        // This is where things go wrong. x doesn't have a property Provider
        x.Provider --> patients.Provider 
    @>
)
```

I tried coercing and casting `x` to an `IQueryable` at some places but that doesn't work.

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) in the docs for `DbSet` it does implement the `IQueryable` interface via `DbQuery`, but does so by "explicitly" implementing the properties.

In [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) there is a Function `As` so you can tell it to treat it as a `IQueryable` that looks like:

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Blog>>(); 
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Blog>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?

Comment: @GertArnold The property `x.Provider` cannot be accessed (because it is an explicit interface implementation) - I think the question is quite clear.

Comment: How do I explain this. I know the provider is an indispensable part of a `DbSet`, but you'll never access it in application code. So you don't want to unit test it. Still something must have triggered you to try and mock it, which is this something that "didn't work".

Comment: @GertArnold see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/data/dn314429.aspx#queryTest

Comment: @albertjan implementing multiple interfaces is not supported in Foq 1.6. I've now added an As method to handle this scenario which should be available in the next release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest release of Foq ([1.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Foq/1.7.0)), now supports implementing multiple interfaces using a `Mock.As` method, similar to the setup in Moq, e.g.

```
type IFoo = 
    abstract Foo : unit -> int

type IBar =
    abstract Bar : unit -> int

[<Test>]
let ``can mock multiple interface types using setup`` () =
    let x = 
        Mock<IFoo>().Setup(fun x -> <@ x.Foo() @>).Returns(2)
         .As<IBar>().Setup(fun x -> <@ x.Bar() @>).Returns(1)
         .Create()    
    Assert.AreEqual(1, x.Bar())
    Assert.AreEqual(2, (x :?> IFoo).Foo())
```